# Azure Functions with Python and Premium Plan: Despite version 3.8. selected 3.6. gets deployed

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I deployed an Azure Functions App with Python `3.8`. Later on I tried to use dataclasses and it failed with the exception that the version available does not support dataclasses. I then SSHed to the host of the Function App and by using `python --version` figured out that version `3.6` was actually installed. As dataclasses are available from `3.7` on it makes sense why this module can't be used.

But what can I do to actually have version `3.8` running on the Function App host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue (see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/39124/azure-functions-always-using-python-36.html) and hopefully fixed soon.

As workaround you can run the following command e.g. in the Cloud shell:

`az functionapp config set --name <func app name> --resource-group <rg name> --subscription <subscription id> --linux-fx-version "DOCKER|mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0.13353-python3.8-appservice"`

After that you need to wait for a while so that the function app becomes usable again. Additionally I have made the experience that the installed packages are gone. Therefore you need also to republish your functions (having the necessary packages defined in `requirements.txt`).

Comment: I did that but now I get this error in the pipeline `##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Conflict (CODE: 409)`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this problem downgrading to Python 3.6 is a workaround.

I tried @quervernetzt solution but it didn't work, my pipelines started giving the following error.

```
##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Conflict (CODE: 409)
```

Comment: Strange, for me it worked (multiple times). Have you encountered this issue also after waiting for some time respectively restarting the app? Or maybe tried once to publish it directly (e.g. via VS Code or directly using the Function Core Tools)?

Comment: And downgrading is no option if you rely on features that are not available in 3.6

Comment: @quervernetzt Yes we waited but it didn't work. Luckily for us Python 3.6 will do just fine for now. Any idea how can I track when Msft fix it?

Comment: @quervernetzt nice. I'll try it out next time.